# what is the powershell equivalent to az acr login

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-container-registry

Using powershell how do we login to Azure Container registry. The sample provided is only for is only for Azure CLI

```
az acr login --name <acrName>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single powershell to login in Azure Container registry, if you want use powershell to login in, we should [get the admin credentials for the registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.containerregistry/get-azurermcontainerregistrycredential?view=azurermps-6.2.0) first and run [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) to log in.

You could refer to the command below.

```
$creds = Get-AzureRmContainerRegistryCredential -Registry $registry
$creds.Password | docker login $registry.LoginServer -u $creds.Username --password-stdin
```

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-powershell#log-in-to-registry).

Answer (score 7):

```
Connect-AzContainerRegistry -Name MyContainerRegistry
```

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerregistry/connect-azcontainerregistry)

Available as part of the official Az Powershell module. Note that the older AzureRM module does not include this functionality.